# I can't post comment via REST API

Tags: comments, rest-api, api

I try to insert comment via REST API , but i get this error :

```
Query parameter not permitted: author
```

I followed this [docs](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/comments/#create-a-comment)  and author is one of the arguments
this is the link test that i use

```
https://www.myblog.com/wp-json/wp/v2/comments/?author=1&content="TestComment"&post=1
```

So, what i am doing wrong ?

Comment: Creating comments via the REST API requires [authentication](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/authentication/), and the authenticated user also needs the `edit_posts` capability - i.e. permissions to edit posts - in order to use the `author` parameter.

Answer (score 1):

I do not recommend doing this. It's better if you authenticate your users, but you can make an api endpoint that posts a comment like this:

```
add_action('rest_api_init',
    function () {
    register_rest_route(
        'api',
        'api_post_comment',
        array(
            'methods'  => 'GET',
            'callback' => 'api_post_comment',
        )
    );
});

function api_post_comment() {
    wp_insert_comment([
        'comment_approved' => 0,
        'comment_author' => 'test',
        'comment_author_email' => 'test@test.com',
        'comment_author_IP' => $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'],
        'comment_content' => 'test',
        'comment_parent' => 0,
        'comment_post_ID' => 25084,
    ]);
}
```

You can learn more here:
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_comment/

and here:
https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/adding-custom-endpoints/